# What should be done if user approves other answer by mistake?

Tags: support

I have given two answers to this [question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/120200/25879). OP considered my [first post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/120201/25879) as an answer but approved [second one](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/120203/25879). I intimated the user about the mistake (through comments) but the user didn't respond.

**Edit:** I think the user realized and done necessary action

But What should I do if it repeats again

Answer (score 3):

You can just comment and explain what is wrong with the answer; if it is utterly wrong, you can also down-vote it.
Apart that, there is nothing else that can be done. Moderators don't delete a question just because it is wrong; that is exactly what down-votes should be used for.

In the case the answer was given by you, and accepted by the OP, you cannot anymore delete it since it was accepted. You can just flag it for moderation attention, explaining you want it deleted because it is utterly wrong.
Keep in mind that, if you do this for most of your answers, moderators could investigate what happens to see if you are rage-quitting for any reason. In any case, moderators could decide not do delete the answer, even if I think it is a rare case (although possible). If that happens, don't vandalize your own answer; eventually, you can add a note for the future readers, to let them know the answer is not correct.

Comment: The OP specifically asks about two answers to the same question he has given himself, where (presumably in the opinion of the OP) the least helpful one was accepted. You can't downvote yourself.

Comment: My answer is still valid as general case; I added the part about answers given from the user who notices their own accepted answer is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I really think this is a non-issue.  How *often* do you give *two* alternative answers to the same question?  I know that it is permitted, but IMHO, best practice is to give one answer.  If you think alternative approaches deserves to be mentioned, describe them in the *same* answer.

But in the rare cases when this happens, it is easy enough for the *user* to fix.  AFAIK, a user can switch to a different accepted answer at any time.  I don't think there is more to do than you've already done: Use *comment* to enlighten the user.  It even looks like you managed to get through in the end :-).

As for the (now hypothetical) case that the users mark of approval stays with the "wrong" answer, I suggest you forget about it and move on.  The person asking the question is the one that places the check-mark.  That is the way it should be. Moderators should not (and do not) interfere with voting or with what is accepted.

There is a lot of (IMHO) wrong answers on Drupal.SE that are accepted *and* upvoted. One more or less does not make a difference. Here is a rather curious example, since a lot of famous Drupalistas are involved: [How can I obscure what I am using to run my site?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/237/how-can-i-obscure-the-fact-my-site-uses-drupal/239#239) (I know that author of the accepted answer - @greggles, author of the Drupal security bible "Cracking Drupal" - is just being ironic. But is irony permitted on Drupal.SE? And do all the people who've starred this get the joke?).

Comment: I don't see the irony: greggles is just saying what you should do to avoid your site is identified as a Drupal site; you can try doing that, if you want to waste your time. ;-)

Comment: @kiamlaluno, if the answer is not irony, then it is wrong.  You have to do a *lot more* things than those mentioned by greggles to avoid your site is identified as a Drupal site (you need to change the standard path to the theme for instance, and change the name of core-generated style-sheet classes). Same with JavaScript (as mentioned by  Mołot in a comment). He just listed enough items to make it obvious that this is a rather pointless excercise.

Comment: It is not wrong: greggles gave a partial list of things to do, and a link to his blog article. What reported in the answer is enough to let future readers understand it is not something they would do. And yes, answers that say "it is not possible" are acceptable, as long as the answers explain exactly why it is not possible. This is what greggles's answer does. He was not supposed to make a copy-pasta of his blog article.